# Can you divide the entries of two tables?

Tags: stata, percentage, tabulate

I have 2 tables in Stata: one shows the count of total parents in each state that had a divorce in the specific divorce year cohort,  the other shows the count of divorced parents with `csphycus == 2` in each state and divorce year cohort.

I want a table that displays the percentage of parents who has `csphycus ==2` for each state and each divorce year cohort.
So  I want to divide the counts in these two tables. How should I do it?

Comment: The images you linked to are not showing. In general, read the Stata tag wiki to learn about posting data examples people can use and showing the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your mean is

```
egen double numer = total(rdasecwt * (csphycus == 2)), by(statefip yrdivbin) 
egen double denom = total(rdasecwt), by(statefip yrdivbin) 
gen wanted = 100 * numer/denom
```

You can show it by some variation on

```
tabdisp statefip yrdivbin, c(wanted) format(%2.1f)
```